# Why the interval will become faster and faster if I keep setting new interval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am doing a very simple timer with two buttons: `stop` and `set`.

Here is the code:

```
   <h1>0</h1>
   <button onclick = 'set()'>Set</button>
   <button onclick = 'stop()'>Stop</button>
```

```
     var click = false;
        let interval
    function set(){
        interval = setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector('h1').textContent = parseFloat(document.querySelector('h1').textContent)+1
        },1000)
    }
    function stop(){
        window.clearInterval(interval)
    }
```

I found that if I keep pressing the `set` button which will set new interval, the speed of adding 1 to `h1` will become faster and faster (which is much faster than 1000 ms).

I know I could gather the two buttons to one button, or make the set button become `display: none` or use other ways to prevent this situation.

But I just wonder why does this happens.

Could someone explain me a little bit about why this happens?

Thanks for any responds?

Comment: It's really very simple.... you are creating multiple setInterval. It is not one getting faster but rather multiple firing at different times

Comment: You are not cleaning up your previous interval unless you explicitly click the stop button. You can instead just call `stop()` as the first operation of `set()`'s logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are not clearing the previous interval (simply reassigning it) on your `set` function, so if you click on `set` three times, you are running three intervals.

The proper code should be:

```
function set(){
  clearInterval(interval);

  interval = setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector('h1').textContent = parseFloat(document.querySelector('h1').textContent)+1
  }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: I reassign the previous interval. Doesn't it means that the value of `interval` will be changed and the interval will be automactially closed or I must use `clearinterval` to stop it?

Comment: You must still use clearInterval

Answer (score 2):

an other way, more user friendly ?

```js
const h1_element = document.querySelector('h1')
    , btSet      = document.querySelector('#bt-set')
    , btStop     = document.querySelector('#bt-stop')
    ;
var interval = 0
  , counter  = 0
  ;
btSet.onclick =()=>
  {
  btSet.disabled = true
  btStop.disabled = false
  interval = setInterval( ()=> { h1_element.textContent = ++counter }, 1000 )
  }
btStop.onclick =()=>
  {
  clearInterval(interval)
  btSet.disabled  = false
  btStop.disabled = true
  }
```

```html
<h1>0</h1>
<button id="bt-set">Set</button>
<button id="bt-stop" disabled>Stop</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing me another useful way!

Answer (score 1):

an other way ? More **RELIABLE** , More **elegant**

Leveraging OOP: where you guarantee a **unique** interval is running per **instance**

```js
class IntervalManager {
   constructor(fn, delay){ this.fn= fn; this.delay= delay;}
   start() {this.stop(); this.id= setInterval(this.fn, this.delay);}
   stop() {if (this.id) clearInterval(this.id);}
}
//--- use it now

const counter = new IntervalManager(function(){
  let ui = document.querySelector('h1')
  ui.textContent = parseFloat(ui.textContent)+1
},1000);
```

```html
<h1>0</h1>
<button onclick = 'counter.start()'>Set</button>
<button onclick = 'counter.stop()'>Stop</button>
```

Other examples below show the benefit of using this manager:

```js
class IntervalManager {
   constructor(fn, i){ this.fn= fn; this.i= i;}
   start() {this.stop(); this.id= setInterval(this.fn, this.i);}
   stop() {if (this.id) clearInterval(this.id);}
}
//--- use it now
//-- example 1
const timer = new IntervalManager(() => {
  document.querySelector('#timer h4').textContent = new Date()
}, 1000)

//-- example 2
counterIncrem= 0
const counter = new IntervalManager(() => {
  counterIncrem++;
  document.querySelector('#counter h4').textContent = counterIncrem
}, 1000)
```

```html
<section id="timer">
  <h1>Timer</h1>
  <h4>_</h4>
  <button onclick = 'timer.start()'>Start</button>
  <button onclick = 'timer.stop()'>Stop</button>
</section>


<section id="counter">
  <h1>counter</h1>
  <h4>_</h4>
  <button onclick = 'counter.start()'>Start</button>
  <button onclick = 'counter.stop()'>Stop</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for opening a new door for me! I just wonder what is the `interval manager`? Is it a library in js or something else? Could you me some details about it because I try to search online, but can't find too many useful information. Thanks for the help!

Comment: it's a concept! and technically, i added there as simple/small class .. No more  We are builder of many JS libs. We are able to provide library in 3 lines   as above (IntervalManager class)